# How to format column only Data to display as Pie Chart in Looker Studio?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, looker-studio, looker

[This is the Sheets Sheet I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsHdZ.png)
I want to create a pie chart in my Looker report that contains a dynamically adjusting pie chart where the sum of the Colums: Sum for Australia, Sum for Austria, Sum for China, etc. is displayed.
[In the report I only managed to create a table that displays the data however this only works because I do not pick any Dimension and add everything as a metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkbTi.png)
However if I try to turn this table into a pie chart only nonsense appears as you can see in the screenshot.

Do I need to reformat my Sheets sheet? Or is there a way to create this pie chart without touching the Sheets sheet?

I played around with the Looker studio properties for hours now but got nothing to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to unpivot your google sheet so that the data looks like this. with a column for country.

[image]

Ben Collins has a great post on how to do this https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/unpivot-in-google-sheets/

let me know if this answers your question